# Shortest code to create a string with specified lengh

Tags: objective-c

What is the shortest way to create a string with spaces and desired length in Objective-C?

I can do it using `for` cycle, but it's several lines of code.

Comment: Kind of related: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returns first six characters

```
NSString *fullName = @"Warif Akhand Rishi";
NSString *subString = [fullName substringToIndex:6];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) ?

```
[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%20d", 42];
```

Comment: Cool. I was using it for concatenating strings only.

Comment: But ok, lets say I have a variable Length which is a length of the required string. How to put this %Length in stringWithFormat method call?